# What do you call this thing in probability theory?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have studied it before but I forgot the name.

It is like when the possiblity of something happens is so small, but you created the experience so so many times, then the probability of that thing to happen is high.

It is like:
the possibility of having a life in a planet is $2\times10^{-17}\%$ but there are $5\times10^{19}$ planets, so the probablity of having a life becomes higher.

**I know i did a wrong maybe example, but i am asking about the name of that field (or theory)**

Comment: You might get better responses if you format your post a little better. Use capitalization and spell words out ("you" instead of "u").

Comment: Are you referring to [the Law of Large Numbers](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Law_of_large_numbers)? The wording of your example is not quite correct (the probability of an event does not 'become higher' under such circumstances), so I thought I would ask in a comment rather than risk posting an irrelevant answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't about the laws of large numbers - it sounds to me like Marco is thinking of expectation, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: An event with very small but positive probability will eventually occur almost surely infinitely many times if the experiment is repeated enough times. The Borel-Cantelli Lemma may be related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result

Comment: @DanielLittlewood: What makes you so sure? The second sentence in the question is quite close to saying 'even if the probability of a particular experimental result is small, we can still *expect* it to happen at least once if we perform the same experiment a large number of times', which, to my mind, is an informally stated consequence of the LLN. The concept of expectation is not really enough: it is the LLN which allows us to *expect* its occurrence, given enough trials.

Comment: @WillR I think I might agree with you. The reason I thought this *wasn't* about the LLN is because of the part "so the probability of having a life becomes higher", but of course in the law of large numbers your actual probability of finding life on a particular planet doesn't change. I think I suggested expectation in the same sense you suggest the LLN, and I think Borel-Cantelli actually captures the concept better than either of them.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Borel-Cantelli may well be relevant, but it seems too technical to be the sought response (no offence meant to Marco here, of course; I just feel that if such a technical result from measure theory is really being referred to, then it is unlikely that the question would be couched in such a down-to-earth setting as having actual numbers representing the probabilities!).

Comment: @WillR I agree that the theorem itself is too hard, but the spirit of it (e.g. if you flip a coin a large number of times, the likelihood of getting 0 heads is very small) is pretty straightforward. An intuitive argument for it could be very simple.

Comment: thanks for all your contribution, but it seems the example of the life outside is not according to the laws of large numbers, i hope u help me out here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly you're thinking of the Poisson distribution.

Suppose you have a one-in-$1{,}000{,}000$ chance of success on each trial, and there are $3{,}600{,}000$ trials.  The expected number of successes is then $3.6$.  If we ask for the probability that there are exactly $5$ successes, we get
$$
\frac{3.6^5 e^{-3.6}}{5!} = \frac{3.6^5 e^{-3.6}}{120} \approx 0.13768. 
$$
Ladislaus Bortkiewicz's book *The Law of Small Numbers*, published in 1898, used the Poisson distribution to model the number of soldiers in the Prussian cavalry each year killed by being kicked by a horse. He also applied it to data on suicides by pre-pubescent children.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may be referring to [the Law of Large Numbers](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Law_of_large_numbers). The Wikipedia page linked to gives a good explanation, from what I can see. See also:

- [the relevant part of this SE
  answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947442/what-makes-a-theorem-fundamental/947466#947466) for more information on the theorem, and why it is important,
- [this SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125087/is-the-law-of-large-numbers-empirically-proven?rq=1) for another good, layman oriented explanation of the theorem,
- the top-rated answer to [this SE
  question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401329/law-of-large-numbers-a-confusion), explaining away one person's confusion over the consequences of the theorem.

Comment: i don't think that is the one i am looking for, i am looking for a theory that says that even if the probability for one shot is small, doing that shot too too too too too many times, i will end up with even a bitter probability or with a sure probability

Comment: So, you mean to say you're looking for a description of a situation in which the probability of an event is affected by the *number of trials so far*? For example, if I flip a coin repeatedly, and every time I get a 'tails' result I add some weight to the 'tails' side of the coin so that the coin is more likely to come up 'heads' next time I flip it?